# How to search for and replace a term within another search term

Tags: python, regex, search, vim, replace

I have a url I get from parsing a swagger's api.json file in Python.

The URL looks something like this and I want to replace the dashes with underscores, but only inside the curly brackets.

```
10.147.48.10:8285/pet-store-account/{pet-owner}/version/{pet-type-id}/pet-details-and-name
```

So, `{pet-owner}` will become `{pet_owner}`, but `pet-store-account` will remain the same.

I am looking for a regular expression that will allow me to perform a non-greedy search and then do a search-replace on each of the first search's findings.

a Python `re` approach is what I am looking for, but I will also appreciate if you can suggest a Vim one liner.

The expected final result is:

```
10.147.48.10:8285/pet-store-account/{pet_owner}/version/{pet_type_id}/pet-details-and-name
```

Comment: Try [`-(?=[^{}]*})`](https://regex101.com/r/xDnsWN/2/) and replace each match with `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a two-step approach:

```
import re

url = "10.147.48.10:8285/pet-store-account/{pet-owner}/version/{pet-type-id}/pet-details-and-name"

rx = re.compile(r'{[^{}]+}')

def replacer(match):
    return match.group(0).replace('-', '_')

url = rx.sub(replacer, url)
print(url)
```

Which yields

```
10.147.48.10:8285/pet-store-account/{pet_owner}/version/{pet_type_id}/pet-details-and-name
```

This looks for pairs of `{` and `}` and replaces every `-` with `_` inside it.
There may be solutions with just one line but this one is likely to be understood in a couple of months as well.

---

Edit: For one-line-gurus:

```
url = re.sub(r'{[^{}]+}',
        lambda x: x.group(0).replace('-', '_'),
        url)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jan. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you expect all '{...}' blocks to be consistent, you may use a trailing context to determine whether a given dash is inside a block, actually just requiring it to be followed by '...}' where '.' is not a '{'

```
exp = re.compile(r'(?=[^{]*})-')
```

...

```
substituted_url = re.sub(exp,'_',url_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [lookahead](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@=) and [lookbehind](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@%3C=) in Vim:

```regex
s/\({[^}]*\)\@<=-\([^{]*}\)\@=/_/g
```

The pattern has three parts:

`\({[^}]*\)\@<=` matches, but does not consume, an opening brace followed by anything except a closing brace, immediately behind the next part.

`-` matches a hyphen.

`\([^{]*}\)\@=` matches, but does not consume, anything except an opening brace, followed by a closing brace, immediately ahead of the previous part.

The same technique can't be exactly followed in Python regular expressions, because they only allow fixed-width lookbehinds.

**Result:**

*Before*

```
outside-braces{inside-braces}out-again{in-again}out-once-more{in-once-more}
```

*After*

```
outside-braces{inside_braces}out-again{in_again}out-once-more{in_once_more}
```

Because it checks for braces in the right place both before and after the hyphen, this solution (unlike others which use only lookahead assertions) behaves sensibly in the face of unmatched braces:

*Before*

```
b-c{d-e{f-g}h-i
b-c{d-e}f-g}h-i
b-c{d-e}f-g{h-i
b-c}d-e{f-g}h-i
```

*After*

```
b-c{d-e{f_g}h-i
b-c{d_e}f-g}h-i
b-c{d_e}f-g{h-i
b-c}d-e{f_g}h-i
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution in Vim:**

```
%s/\({.*\)\@<=-\(.*}\)\@=/_/g
```

**Explanation of matched pattern:**

```
\({.*\)\@<=-\(.*}\)\@=

\({.*\)\@<=                 Forces the match to have a {.* behind 

           -                Specifies a dash (-) as the match

            \(.*}\)\@=      Forces the match to have a .*} ahead
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. Works like a charm.

Comment: @RaamEE I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use python lookahead to ignore the string enclosed within curly brackets `{}`:

**Description:**

`(?=...)`:
Matches if `...` matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac `(?=Asimov)` will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

**Solution**

```
a = "10.147.48.10:8285/pet-store-account/**{pet-owner}**/version/**{pet-type-id}**/pet-details-and-name"
import re
re.sub(r"(?=[^{]*})-", "_", a)
```

**Output:**

```
'10.147.48.10:8285/pet-store-account/**{pet_owner}**/version/**{pet_type_id}**/pet-details-and-name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do in Vim is to use a sub-replace-expression:

```
:%s/{\zs[^}]*\ze}/\=substitute(submatch(0),'-','_','g')/g
```

Using `\zs` and `\ze` we set the match between the `{` & `}` characters. Using `\={expr}` will evaluate `{expr}` as the replacement for each substitution. Using VimScripts substitution function, `substitute({text}, {pat}, {replace}, {flag})`, on the entire match, `submatch(0)`, to convert `-` to `_`.

For more help see:

```
:h sub-replace-expression
:h /\zs
:h submatch()
:h substitute()
```